# Angular (6) Marking multiple checkboxes as checked or unchecked on page load based on API values

Tags: angular, primeng

Trying to teach myself Angular (6) with TypeScript (using PrimeNg controls by recommendation) and I've been struggling with getting multiple check boxes to load their value from an array of objects that are populated from my API.

Essentially, I have two data sets that come from my API: fruits[] and userFavFruits[]. My goal is to display a list of checkboxes that based on the userFavFruits[] retrieved from the API for the current user, will check their associated fruit checkbox when the page loads.

I've tried several different approaches that I've found on here and online but nothing seems to be working as I thought.

This is loading every checkbox as selected and not caring if the id in userFavFruits[] exists in fruits[] and selecting based on that. This is what I am unsure on how to accomplish.

HTML:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
Fruits:
  <p-checkbox *ngFor="let fruit of fruits;let userFavFruit of 
    userFavFruits;"
    [(ngModel)]="userFavFruit.FruitId" binary="true"
    label="{{fruits.Id}} : {{fruits.Name}}" id="fruits.Id" name="User 
    Favorite Fruits">
  </p-checkbox> 
</div>
```

TypeScript classes:

```
export class UserFavFruit{
    UserFruitId: number;
    UserId: number;
    FruitId: number;
}

export class Fruit {
    FruitId: number;
    FruitName: string;
}
```

In my component I retrieve the data from my API on the ngOnInit():

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getFruits(); //populates fruits[]
    this.getUserFavFruits();//populates userFavFruits[]
}
```

Comment: If you really want help you should provide some stackblitz link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all you should not bind the id value to checkbox since it can only carries the two states ( `true` and `false` OR `on` and `off` etc).
2. You should create extra field say `selected` into the `Fruit` class. Whose values will be set to true if the `id` matched with one of the `fruit` of `UserFavoriteFruit[]`.
3. This `selected` property will be bound with checkbox. Now if user does change in the `checkbox` value will be synced with the property `selected`.
4. The last issue with your code is related to the way you iterating the `arrays` for `fruits` and `userFavouitesFruit` together. You just need to iterate over one array that is `fruits`.

Sample demo is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w1tr5u

Comment: This helped a lot. Both from the explanations and the demo.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use two lists, I think you should have only one with a boolean indicating if this fruit needs to be selected e.g.

```
export class Fruit {
        FruitId: number;
        FruitName: string;
        isFavorite: boolean;
    }
```

Your [(ngModel)] needs to be wired on this boolean witch you will be able to set on true or false from you're API :

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
Fruits:
  <p-checkbox *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
    [(ngModel)]="fruit.isFavorite" binary="true"
    label="{{fruits.Id}} : {{fruits.Name}}" id="fruits.Id" name="User 
    Favorite Fruits">
  </p-checkbox> 
</div>
```

Comment: There are absolutely valid use cases for two models, however. So from an API design standpoint returning a single `UserFavoriteFruit[]` is better, for the sake of the using the second array would probably be better.